# CORS error when accessing local JSON file using vanilla JS AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to use a vanilla JS AJAX request to pull back a JSON string from a locally stored JSON file (specifically trying not to use JQuery) - the below code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388452/how-do-i-load-a-json-object-from-a-file-with-ajax/14388512#14388512) - but I keep getting an error in the Chrome console (see below). Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I have tried changing the positioning of the xhr.open & .send requests, but still get error messages.  I suspect the issue lies with the .send() request?

```
//Vanilla JS AJAX request to get species from JSON file & populate Select box
function getJSON(path,callback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                                         //Instantiate new request

    xhr.open('GET', path ,true);                                            //prepare asynch GET request
    xhr.send();                                                             //send request

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){                                    //everytime ready state changes (0-4), check it
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {                                         //if request finished & response ready (4)
            if (xhr.status === 0 || xhr.status === 200) {                   //then if status OK (local file || server)
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);                    //parse the returned JSON string
                if (callback) {callback(data);}                             //if specified, run callback on data returned
            }
        }
    };
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Test execute above function with callback
getJSON('js/species.json', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

The console in Chrome is throwing this error:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/brett/Desktop/SightingsDB/js/species.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Would be grateful for any insights - many thanks.

Comment: it is a problem about security, try to run it in your localhost server or in live

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? It clearly says that CORS is not supported for the `file` protocol.

Comment: Modern browsers treat every `file://` URL as if it were a different domain.

Comment: Obviously, you're running the script directly from filesystem, instead of from HTTP server. (as @Özgür Ersil suggested)

Comment: Correct, thanks all - I am running from the filesystem as I am trying to create a self contained project that I can send on to someone later without having to set up server, db etc. Am I smoking my socks?

Comment: You simply can't make Ajax requests to the local file system.

Comment: OK got it, thanks. Basically, SFQ...

Comment: This solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically as Felix, error msg, et al below say - simply can't run an AJAX request against a local file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the application on local server like apache or wamp then you will not face any issue