# readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, readfile

I am relatively new to Node.js and have been looking around but cannot find a solution. I did check the require javascript file and it does not seem to have a method for "readFileSync". Perhaps I don't have a proper require file? I had a hard time finding this file, everywhere talked about it but most people did not post where to get it.

I installed Node.js and have the require.js file. My current code is like this:

```
fs = require(['require'], function (foo) {
//foo is now loaded.
});
console.log("\n *STARTING* \n");
// Get content from file
var contents = fs.readFileSync("sliderImages", 'utf8');
```

I had a bit at first getting require to work however it seems to load the require JavaScript file. I have been following guides and I am not sure why I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

I have tried many fixes and cannot seem to figure this one out.

Comment: `fs` obviously isn't Node's "fs", otherwise the `readFileSync` method wouldn't be undefined, so you're doing something wrong with your require? Why wouldn't you just do `var fs = require('fs')`

Comment: Don't use Require.js with Node. Node has it's own way of handling modules using CommonJS. As adeneo said, just do `var fs = require('fs')`. Require.js is for module loading on the client-side.

Comment: When I tried using that I got the following error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]). So I began looking for a solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using requirejs in node? If there is, are you importing it?

Comment: I dont have a file called fs, is that a problem? Again I do not know where to get this file.

Comment: I am just trying to read a json file using node.

Comment: There is no file for `fs`, it's a built in module that is always there

Comment: How are you running this file? Are you running it from the command prompt?

Comment: Sounds like the code is running in a browser, with requireJS, that would produce the error `Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet...`, it has to run ***in*** NodeJS.

Comment: I am doing them in a javascript page that is loaded by the browser

Comment: The browser doesn't have access to the file system, and it's ***not*** NodeJS either, so `fs` can't be used in a browser.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Node.js does not use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/). Require.js was built so that you could have asynchronous module loading on the client-side (in your browser).

Node.js uses [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) style modules. Your code using CommonJS would look like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("\n *STARTING* \n");
var contents = fs.readFileSync("sliderImages", "utf8");
```

If we assume you saved this in a file called `main.js` you would then enter this command in your console (make sure you are in the same directory as the file):

```
node main.js
```

This code *will not* run in the browser. Node.js runs on the server. If you want to load a JSON file on the browser side then you'll need to load it using AJAX. [There are numerous resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388452/how-do-i-load-a-json-object-from-a-file-with-ajax) available to show you how to do this. Be aware that you must either run your page from a server or have a special flag enabled to load in files from the file system.

Comment: Thank you I was a bit un certain how to use node.js, that cleared a lot up, thank you!

Comment: It seems to me that RequireJS supports Node?: https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Comment: @kip2 RequireJS does work in a Node environment but Node does not support RequireJS style modules by default. Node handles modules in its own way. There's no reason to use RequireJS in Node, especially since client-side bundling has advanced a lot since the time that RequireJS was built

Comment: Hi @MikeCluck, my situation isn't exactly like OP's. I'm trying to use a node module in a script that's supposed to run browser/client side, by doing `import config from './config/env_config'` ,but was getting this `FileSystem.readFileSync is not a function` error. `env_config` is actually just a wrapper around node-config that I use to manage environment config values

Answer (score 3):

This error can arise if you write

`const fs = import('fs');`

in a Node module

but should write

`import fs from 'fs';`