# How to use jaeger-client from react component?

Tags: reactjs, opentracing, jaeger

From react application (App.js ) imported jaeger-client.

`import jaegerClient from 'jaeger-client'`

Got exception 'TypeError: _fs2.default.readFileSync is not a function' from following line of /node_modules/jaeger-client/dist/src/thrift.js:168

`source: _fs2.default.readFileSync(_path2.default.join(__dirname, './jaeger-idl/thrift/jaeger.thrift'), 'ascii')`

Trying to solve it. Thanks for any help.

Complete package.json is like below

`{
  "name": "calculator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://ahfarmer.github.io/calculator",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.4.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.1.0",
    "big.js": "^5.0.3",
    "bufferutil": "^3.0.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "github-fork-ribbon-css": "^0.2.1",
    "hexer": "^1.5.0",
    "jaeger-client": "^3.10.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-tracing": "^0.1.5",
    "thrift": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
     "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
    }
}`

Forked from https://github.com/ahfarmer/calculator and I am trying to trace every user action ( button press ). To test tracing from react.js application.

Answer (score 2):

node-jaeger-client currently doesn't run in the browser. There is ongoing [work](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-node/issues/109) to make jaeger-client browser friendly. This issue: [readFileSync is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418513/readfilesync-is-not-a-function) contains relevant information to why you're seeing the error message. Essentially, you're trying to run jaeger-client (a nodejs library) using react-scripts which doesn't contain the modules that jaeger-client needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not jaeger, able to send traces to zipkin server, using zipkin-simple. 
Related code is in repository https://github.com/debmalya/calculator

```
import zipkinSimple from 'zipkin-simple'
const zipkinTracerSimple = new zipkinSimple({
             debug: true,
             host: "localhost",
             port: "9411",
             path: "/api/v2/spans",
             sampling: 1.0,
})

var zipkinSimpleTraceData

zipkinSimpleTraceData= zipkinTracerSimple.getChild(zipkinSimpleTraceData);
    zipkinSimpleTraceData = 
zipkinTracerSimple.sendClientSend(zipkinSimpleTraceData, {
     service: '<service_name>',
     name: "<span_name>"
   })
```