# fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am using [rn-nodeify](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify) for enabling the use of [pdf2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json) in React Native. pdf2json uses `fs` for loading files using the method `readFileSync`. I am getting this error when I try to use the library:

```
fs.readFileSync is not a function. (In 'fs.readFileSync(_basePath + fieldName, 'utf8')', 'fs.readFileSync' is undefined)
```

I cannot find any support for this issue. Any pointers appreciated.

Edit: Please note that I am not trying to run this in a browser. This pertains to react-native i.e. it runs on a device, and the code should have access to the file system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [readFileSync is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418513/readfilesync-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Checkout this [comment](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify/issues/11#issuecomment-270061819), you can try if async is working or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response Pritish! That looks relevant. Since the method call is in a 3rd party library, I would prefer to try other options before changing that. Do you know how I can make fs point to react-native-fs instead of react-native-level-fs?

Comment: I don't know if the react-native supports the synchronous functions. You may use async await in your async func as `let file = await fs.readFile` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I came across this problem while writing tests in ES6/latest JS - fixed this by changing the import from:

`import { fs } from 'fs';`

to

`import fs from 'fs';`

Notice the unnecessary `{}` - fs is the default export from the fs node module and should be imported in the latter way

For a better explanation on default & named exports please see [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281)