# What's the right way to load json files in browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have built a node library loading json files like this

```
var FILE_PATH = path.join(
  __dirname,
  '../data/data.json'
);

function loadMyJsonFile() {
  return JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(
      FILE_PATH,
      constants.DEFAULT_ENCODING
    )
  );
}
```

The code works fine on server side.
I see this error in Chrome console when the function is executed in browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

I googled a bit and I don't think I can use `fs` in browser code.
What's the right way of loading json files in browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a JSON object from a file with ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388452/how-do-i-load-a-json-object-from-a-file-with-ajax)

Comment: Essentially that data.json is local to your computer, so when a server is running it can load that just fine. Now on the client side of things, when they request a file with fs, that doesn't make sense anymore. You need to have a way of serving the file to the client through a separate HTTP request.

Comment: You can't read files directly in a browser unless the web page itself is a file URL, so you would typically put the JSON file on a web server that will serve it at a particular URL and then use an Ajax call in the browser to fetch it.